# Sharing vagrant with config files

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I just finished my Vagrant box.

It has Gemfire and some other things on it. The provision works great but it has several configuration files that need to go with it.

How can I share my box in a way that the those files are carried with it?

An example:

To start a Gemfire server you need some region configs, so I want my project regions to be there in order for it to start in a ready to develop state.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a feature from Packer. Package the your box with Packer with the Virtualbox builder. First my example and then I will explain the feature. I am using this packer.json to package my vagrant box:

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
        "type": "virtualbox-ovf",
        "source_path": "Redistribution.ovf",
        "ssh_username": "vagrant",
        "ssh_password": "vagrant",
        "ssh_wait_timeout": "10000s",
        "headless": true,
      "guest_additions_mode": "disable",
        "vboxmanage": [
            ["modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--memory", "1024"],
            ["modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--cpus", "2"]
        ],
        "shutdown_command": "echo 'packer' | sudo -S shutdown -P now"
      }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "script": "packer/putInsecureKey.sh"
        }
  ],
  "post-processors": [
    {
        "type":               "vagrant",
        "compression_level":  9,
      "output":             "vagrant-dockerdev.box"
      }
  ]
}
```

I have installed Packer 0.8.1 and run this command on the exported Vagrant box:

```
packer build packer.json
```

The following parameters for the post-processor will put files inside the box which can be referenced by a Vagrantfile. See [Packer Documentation](https://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/vagrant.html).

- include (array of strings) - Paths to files to include in the Vagrant box. These files will each be copied into the top level directory of the Vagrant box (regardless of their paths). They can then be used from the Vagrantfile.
- vagrantfile_template (string) - Path to a template to use for the Vagrantfile that is packaged with the box.

Now back to my example:

```
"post-processors": [
    {
      "type":                 "vagrant",
      "compression_level":    9,
      "output":               "vagrant-dockerdev.box"
      "include":              ["path/to/file1", "path/to/file2"]
      "vagrantfile_template": "path/to/vagrant-template"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer... I was really hoping there was a way to use vagrant box to pack it...  I will probably share the whole thing as a zip because if I complicate it too much no one is going to use it. Thanks !

Comment: You could share it on github inside a repository. Then release it. Github provides ZIP for every release automatically.